# What's wrong with my PDO statement?

Tags: php, pdo

```
// Check for existence - don't add a duplicate
$sqlQuery = $pdo->prepare('SELECT campaign_id FROM campaigns WHERE (customer_id=:customerId) AND (title=:campaignTitle) AND (description=:campaignDescription) AND (start_time=:startTimeStamp) AND (end_time=:endTimeStamp)');

$sqlQuery->bindParam(':customerId', $customerId);  // , PDO::PARAM_INT
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':campaignTitle', $campaignTitle);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':campaignDescription', $campaignDescription);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':startTimeStamp', $campaignTitle);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':endTimeStamp', $endTimeStamp);

$sqlResult = DatabaseCommand($sqlQuery);
```

results in

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':customerId)
>   AND (title=:campaignTitle) AND (description=:campaignDescription) A'
>   at line 1' in E:\coding\Web
>   Development\Xampp\htdocs\api\addCampaign.php:42 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\coding\Web Development\Xampp\htdocs\api\addCampaign.php(42):
>   PDO->query('SELECT campaign...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\coding\Web
>   Development\Xampp\htdocs\api\addCampaign.php on line 42

but I can't see why

---

[Update] for those who wanted to see the code of `DatabaseCommand()` this is pretty much it.

```
function DatabaseCommand($sqlCommand)
{
   $result = $sqlCommand->execute();
   return $result;
}
```

There is some additional code, but that just logs the command for debugging porpoises, checks for errors, logs those, catches exception & emails me.

Comment: The syntax looks fine, so it's most likely a access violation. Make sure you have the required `read` rights on that database/table.

Comment: Parenethis aren't requried. Can you post also DatabaseCommand() method? the query looks like: "SELECT campaign_id FROM campaigns WHERE customer_id=:customerId AND title=:campaignTitle AND description=:campaignDescription AND start_time=:startTimeStamp AND end_time=:endTimeStamp". With the first parenthesis the query is doing where (not set) = (condition=value)

Comment: what is `DatabaseCommand()`? what does it do? this command is not part of standard PDO afaik.

Comment: I will post the code in 8 or 10 hours, when I get back from work (question was posted before leaving home). I can say only that the function has worked for a previous query, so it seem unlikely that it is the problem - but let's wait until you see the code to decide. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Mawg I bet the query you used before wasn't an prepared statement then. You're using `PDO->query()` within the `DatabaseCommand()` function, this can be read out of your Stack Trace you postet. `PDO->query()` won't work with prepared statements, you need to use `PDO->execute()`

Comment: Good point (+1). I **know** that I originally used `execute`, but for this question I tried again with  `query` after reading another SO question. Let me get home & run it with `prepare` and see how it goes ...

Answer (score 2):

**update:** *seems like this isn't the solution, only improves readability*

put a space between `=` and the parameter:

```
$sqlQuery = $pdo->prepare('SELECT campaign_id FROM campaigns WHERE (customer_id= :customerId) AND (title= :campaignTitle) AND (description= :campaignDescription) AND (start_time= :startTimeStamp) AND (end_time= :endTimeStamp)');
```

Comment: Are you **certain**? 1) it sounds strange & 2) this works `$sqlQuery = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE customer_id=:customer');`

Comment: no, i am not certain. i just know that PDO got strange parsing problems. i will test in a sec.

Comment: Despite four upvotes? I wonder sometimes what people here are thinking :-)

Comment: @Mawg ya, same :) it only was a fast guess on my side.

Answer (score 1):

This code you posted here has nothing to do with error message you get.

You have to check addCampaign.php file, line 42 where you are using query() method instead of execute(). And of course you have to check **the actual file that being executed.**

I'll take the opportunity to direct all the enthusiast programmers' attention to the extreme helpfulness of reading error messages. Despite of the common belief, it is not just a reproach, reading "You've done something wrong!", leaving you to guess the reason, but **precise and detailed explanation.**  And it only takes to read the error message to get the clue.

I'll also take the opportunity to direct all the enthusiast programmers' attention to the fact that if common practice of echoing only error message, leaving stack trace behind, were used, the information on the real cause of error were omitted.

Comment: not everybody got the time to analyze, test and write tons of text when answering (or "guessing") at SO. plus, without guessing i would have never solved some serious problems i have had with `PDO` (and its parser).  **guess** what happens with named parameters in commented MySQL code in `PDO`...